# Handle all exceptions

Tags: java, logging, logback

I used `logback` for logging java application. How to i can handle all exceptions in my app with `logback`

My **test** config

```
    <appender name="exceptions" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.core.filter.EvaluatorFilter">
            <evaluator>
                <expression>java.lang.Exception.class.isInstance(throwable)</expression>
            </evaluator>
            <onMatch>ACCEPT</onMatch>
        </filter>
        <file>exceptions.log</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
            <immediateFlush>false</immediateFlush>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you mean catching all exceptions, even those that are not caught: you can define an uncaught exceptions handler in your code, as early as possible:

```
private static void setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler() {
    try {
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler() {
            @Override
            public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e) {
                LOGGER.error("Uncaught Exception detected in thread " + t, e);
            }
        });
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        LOGGER.error("Could not set the Default Uncaught Exception Handler", e);
    }
}
```